# Capture data of a child nodes xml in BAM tool.(BizTalk Business Activity Monitoring)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

I have receive port and simple XML:

```
<root id = “1” name = “name” >
<childs>
<chilId id = “2” />
</childs>
</root>
```

BAM Activity:

```
 id – BD Integer
 name – BD Text
 childId – BD Integer
```

Then bind using TPE message fields to activity fields.

```
 id = root -> id
 name = root -> name
 childId = root.childs.child -> id
```

But in DB I get empty field [childId].
XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://BizTalk_Test.InMsg" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://BizTalk_Test.InMsg" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="childs">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="child">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" />
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Simple message:

```
<root xmlns="http://BizTalk_Test.InMsg" id = "1" name = "Test 1" >
<childs>
<child id = "1" />
</childs>
</root>
```

Result in DB:

```
id  Name    childId
1   Test 1  NULL
```

Comment: Is the any of those nodes repeating in the schema?

Comment: added to the post: XSD & XML

Comment: Question was resolved. It was error in XSD.